# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon after I set -H tcp://X.X.X.X:2375 in the dockerd arguments

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have launched Jenkins as a Docker container and in the Jenkins dashboard I am configuring the Docker plugin to communicate with the Docker daemon. However, when I add "-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375" in the Docker daemon and I restart Docker, executing any docker commands results in the message: "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"

This is the first time I am working with Docker and Jenkins and I have spent a lot of time looking for a solution everywhere.

I have modified the /lib/systemd/system/docker.service by replacing the line:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd
```

with

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
```

Then I restart the Docker daemon:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl reload docker
systemctl restart docker.service
```

I check that the process is listening in the port 2375:

```
netstat -lntp | grep dockerd
tcp6       0      0 :::2375                 :::*                    LISTEN      10855/dockerd
```

When I try any docker command I get the following:

```
docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Comment: _Anyone_ who can reach your system can use Docker commands to read and write _any_ file on your system as root with no authentication or logging at all.  You should remove this setting _immediately_, and reinstall your system if you’re not 100% sure it hasn’t been compromised.

Comment: The Docker container is running in a isolated Virtual Machine only for testing purposes and it contains nothing that could be compromised. Should I still remove the setting? Sorry for the question, but I am very new to networking stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Docker normally listens on the unix socket `/var/run/docker.sock`. You have asked it to instead listen on the tcp socket `tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`, so attempts by the client to connect to the default unix socket will fail.

If you want it to listen to *both* places, then you need:

```
dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2735 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank so much, I was forgetting to also add listening on the default UNIX socket `/var/run/docker.sock`. Now, I can use Jenkins and and its Docker plugin.